# Extracting str from pandas dataframe using json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I read csv file into a dataframe named df

Each rows contains str below.

> '{"id":2140043003,"name":"Olallo Rubio",...}'

I would like to extract "name" and "id" from each row and make a new dataframe to store the str.

I use the following codes to extract but it shows an error. Please let me know if there is any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thanks

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 32 (char 31)

Comment: Are you sure that every JSON in `creator` is validly formatted? Because from the partial sample you provided your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with using [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd

sample = [{
"id": 2140043003,
"name":"Olallo Rubio",
"is_registered": True,
"chosen_currency": None,
"avatar":{
        "thumb":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=40&h=40&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=653706657ccc49f68a27445ea37ad39a",
        "small":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=0bd2f3cec5f12553e679153ba2b5d7fa",
        "medium":"https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=0bd2f3cec5f12553e679153ba2b5d7fa"
        },
"urls":{
        "web":{
                "user":"https://www.kickstarter.com/profile/2140043003"
        },
        "api":{
                "user":"https://api.kickstarter.com/v1/users/2140043003?signature=1531480520.09df9a36f649d71a3a81eb14684ad0d3afc83e03"
        }
    }
}]

# Create datafrane
df = pd.json_normalize(sample)

# Select columns into new dataframe.
df1 = df.loc[:, ["name", "id",]]
```

Check `df1`:

Input:

```
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
           name          id
0  Olallo Rubio  2140043003
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
text={
    "id": 2140043003,
    "name": "Olallo Rubio",
    "is_registered": True,
    "chosen_currency": 'Null',
    "avatar": {
        "thumb": "https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=40&h=40&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=653706657ccc49f68a27445ea37ad39a",
        "small": "https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=0bd2f3cec5f12553e679153ba2b5d7fa",
        "medium": "https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/019/223/259/16513215a3869caaea2d35d43f3c0c5f_original.jpg?w=160&h=160&fit=crop&v=1510685152&auto=format&q=92&s=0bd2f3cec5f12553e679153ba2b5d7fa"
    },
    "urls": {
        "web": {
            "user": "https://www.kickstarter.com/profile/2140043003"
        },
        "api": {
            "user": "https://api.kickstarter.com/v1/users/2140043003?signature=1531480520.09df9a36f649d71a3a81eb14684ad0d3afc83e03"
        }
    }
}
def extract(text,*args):
    list1=[]
    for i in args:
        list1.append(text[i])
    return list1
    
print(extract(text,'name','id'))
# ['Olallo Rubio', 2140043003]
```